# Install a shell script with homebrew -- to install darktable (1_install_hb_dependencies.sh)

Tags: shell-script, package-management, homebrew

I want to build darktable from source w/ homebrew, like so: [doc on Github](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/packaging/macosx/BUILD_hb.txt). I have installed homebrew (step 0). Now I'm stuck at the first step where I need to install ''required homebrew packages'', i.e. `1_install_hb_dependencies.sh` which points me to [a shell script in the repository](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/packaging/macosx/1_install_hb_dependencies.sh).

How do I install that 1_install_hb_dependencies.sh and where?

I unsuccessfully tried a few things like `brew install` and `brew tap -new`. But I'm new to homebrew and don't want to break things (which I think I have managed to do with hb before).

It might be the case that I'm misunderstanding all this and I need to run the script that's in ``1_install_hb_dependencies.sh`in order to install those dependencies. I.e. something like this:`bash <(curl -s https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/packaging/macosx/1_install_hb_dependencies.sh)`inspired from [StackExchange][3]. This didn't work (also tried with`source`instead of`bash```.

Any help appreciated -- thanks!

Edit:
I tried
`curl -s -L https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/packaging/macosx/1_install_hb_dependencies.sh -o 1_install_hb_dependencies.sh` inspired by [this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80027/source-a-script-from-a-url-in-bash). But now I'm stuck again not knowing how to run it. `brew install` doesn't do it. Neither are `bash ./1_install_hb_dependencies.sh`.

Edit 2:
Since `curl` didn't really get me the .sh file but only some kind of response, I downloaded 1_install_hb_dependencies.sh straight from Github and did `chmod +x 1_install_hb_dependencies.sh`. However, `brew install 1_install_hb_dependencies.sh` still doesn't work.